# Using Factory method with Spring xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, factory-pattern

I want to create beans based on a specific type. Ive an abstract class which is extended by two concrete classes whose object I want to instantiate via a Factory (or any other best suited approach) class based on the type.

```
public abstract class Helper{
public abstract boolean check();
} 

public class C1 extends Helper{
      public boolean check(){
 //implementation here
}
}

public class C2 extends Helper{
         public boolean check(){
 //implementation here
}
}

public interface MyFactory{
     public Helper create(){
 }
```

application-context.xml

```
<bean id=.../>
```

How should I do this using dependency injection of Spring via XML?

Also, I tried ServiceLocatorFactoryBean approach but that does not help me pass the object of required type. Followed this link - http://www.jcombat.com/spring/factory-implementation-using-servicelocatorfactorybean-in-spring

Comment: Will using some concrete impl of `Factory` in your `beans.xml` solve your concerns?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your factory (for example `MyFactoryImpl`) and then configure:

```
<bean id="myFactoryImpl" class="com.example.MyFactoryImpl" />

<bean id="c1"
   factory-bean="myFactoryImpl"
   factory-method="create"/>
```

example factory:

```
public class com.example.MyFactoryImpl implements MyFactory {
   public Helper create(){return new C1()}
}
```

*(Spring does not require that `MyFactory` interface)*

Comment: If I use a concrete FactoryImpl, how do I return the instance of type C2? Don't want to use another method to return different instance :/

Comment: @user2340345: it seams that we have a different understanding what a factory is for!  Could it be, that you just need a way to instanciate beens in spring xml, and you do not know how?